# How to use pandas "Grouper" function to create only groups of 10 min while discarding the leftover data, if any?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pd.grouper

My pandas dataframe df is as below:

```
    time_stamp      beats(in sec)   RR          BPM 
0   29140.870816    0.670           0.437757    137 
1   29141.333816    1.133           0.462341    129 
2   29141.823816    1.623           0.490448    122 
3   29142.292816    2.092           0.468517    128 
4   29142.760816    2.560           0.468215    128 
... ... ... ... ... ...
3708    30762.612816    1622.412    0.426784    140 
3709    30763.051816    1622.851    0.439165    136 
3710 rows × 5 columns
```

I want to group this data into 10 min intervals. If the data is more or less than 10 min in the last interval, I have to discard that data. For example, we can make only 2 complete 10 min groups (upto 1200 seconds, using last value of 'beats' column) from the above data. All the data after 1200 seconds is not considered for further analysis. I am using pandas "Grouper" function for this:

```
agg_10m = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='10Min'))
agg_10m.ngroups
```

This is creating 3 groups. How to use "Grouper" function or any other method so that only 2 groups are created. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can't use `pd.Grouper` and `freq` without `key` parameter if your index is not a `DatetimeIndex`. Please provide a full reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I rectified my code to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of try to create only 2 groups, maybe you should filter all values greater than 1200 seconds?

```
>>> df[df['beats(in sec)'] < 1200]]
     time_stamp  beats(in sec)        RR  BPM
0  29140.870816          0.670  0.437757  137
1  29141.333816          1.133  0.462341  129
2  29141.823816          1.623  0.490448  122
3  29142.292816          2.092  0.468517  128
4  29142.760816          2.560  0.468215  128
```

Now you can group with:

```
df[df['beats(in sec)'] < 1200].groupby(pd.Grouper(...)).ngroups
```